# mysql php android. Deleted all rows from a table yet the last one still shows up on listview

Tags: php, android, mysql

my android app inserts and shows queries from mysql database fine.  Yet only problem is when i deleted every row from a table, the last row deleted still shows up on the android application.  Only the last one left will show up.  If there was 5 rows and i deleted one, 4 rows will show (working properly).  But when i keep deleting till there is only one row left even if i delete it over and over again it still shows up.  On phpmyadmin the table is empty yet my app is still showing there is one result left.  When i close the app and open again that row is gone.

I tried figuring this out. I felt it was something to do with the last row being kept in android memory,  1)I tried system.gc();  in android.   2) session_destroy(); in php. 
nothing.

Its not a big problem because there should never be a time when this table is completely empty yet it is bothering me.
Thanks in advance

deletion code
`query="Delete from table where id ="+id;
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       st.executeUpdate(query);`

Comment: Perhaps you should show some code, e.g. how do you delete the row, how do you refresh your view after having deleted the rows etc

Comment: they are in different activities.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove all data from a listArray for ListView.

   ```
   listArray.clear();
   ```
2. When you delete a row, check what exactly you are deleting
   (it has maybe position issue)
3. Check whether you are using another table or not
4. You did,

   ```
   listview.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
   ```

   then, call below after delete last row.

   ```
   yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
   ```

Comment: 0. listArray.clear(); *listArray=your Array name for ListView
1. fetch data from server 
2. listArray.add(newData)
3. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: only have the one table, and clear(); does not work. And when i add a new insert then that one gets shown and the deleted one is gone.

Comment: You have refresh issue I guess. try No.4.